# OpenCV std::vector< cv::Point2f > to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing an application in OpenCV, and on **Windows** the following code is valid, and compiles / works:

```
/* Calculate the transformation points */
std::vector<cv::Point2f> img1;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> img2;
for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ ) {
    img1.push_back( keypoints_imageOne[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    img2.push_back( keypoints_imageTwo[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

/* Generate the homogonous matrix from the transformation points */
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(img1, img2, CV_RANSAC);
```

However, when I switch to either my **Mac** or **Linux** box, I get an error saying that there is no function prototype for the arguments (as the function prototype requires `cv::Mat` in place of the `std::vector< cv::Point2f >`)

So my question is, how can / should I cast from `std::vector < cv::Point2f >` to `cv::Mat` or how should I go about doing this otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you have an older version of OpenCV on Linux. The possibility to use vectors as input to openCV functions is added to ver 2.3, I think.

So, happy update!

Comment: Thanks, just updated and also casting to Mat(img1) removed the error before the update. :D